# Is it possible to divide multiple features at once in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis

I have a hydrographic network layer in ArcGIS Pro and I would like to divide all of the features within it that are more than 1km long so that the layer only contains features 1km long and shorter. This is easy enough to do one feature at a time with the Divide tool under Modify Features but the layer contains 16,467 features greater than 1km and the Divide tool will only accept one feature at a time. Is there a way to divide multiple features at once within ArcGIS Pro?

Thank you very much to anyone who can help.

Comment: Hey Thomas - try posting this question in  https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hey LeasMaps - thanks, I'll try that.